# Camera error: Cannot connect to the camera

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I want to use the built-in camera functionality of a device. having read the documentation, this is the method I am using

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

In the manifest I added the usage:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
              android:required="true" />
```

However, when I invoke the method, the error dialog appears. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

Using camera with ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent with target API 23 or higher requires camera permission. You must request this permission at runtime.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nt5GMaFUvog) you can find a video tutorial on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open the camera on button click, use the code below.

Initialize the button and image view within the onCreate() method.

```
photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST); 
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {  
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
        if(photo!=null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }  
}
```

Comment: What's the value of CAMERA_REQUEST? I've just tested my code (the above one) on a real device and the camera is opened. Any idea why this may happen? Thanks!

Comment: I haven't activated the camera of the device... :D :)

Comment: set CAMERA_REQUEST to 1 like   CAMERA_REQUEST=1